# How to use Assert command?

Tags: java, if-statement, selenium-webdriver

So, I am not sure why my Assertion is not working. Can you please point the mistake? 
PS. I am new to programming and selenium.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(),'Round Trip')]")).click();
         if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(),'Round Trip')]")).isEnabled() ) {
            Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(),'Round Trip')]")).isSelected());

         }
```

I am getting below error in console:

[image]

Comment: The `if` and the `Assert.assertTrue` are testing different conditions: `driver.findElement(...).isEnabled()` vs `driver.findElement(...).isSelected()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to separate your code.

`assertTrue()` returns if it isn't. so you should use `try-catch`.

AS-IS

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(),'Round Trip')]")).click();
         if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(),'Round Trip')]")).isEnabled() ) {
            Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(),'Round Trip')]")).isSelected());

         }
```

TO-BE

```
bool isAssertTrue = true;

try {
Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(),'Round Trip')]"));
} catch (AssertionError e) {
    e.printStackTrac();
    isAssertTrue = false;
}



driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(),'Round Trip')]")).click();
         if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(),'Round Trip')]")).isEnabled() ) {
                if (isAssertTrue) {
                    isSelected()
                } else {
                    // do nothing . . . 
                }
            );

         }
```

Please visit JUnit reference document : [link](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Assert.html#assertTrue(boolean))